# Change a list of matrix elements

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have a matrix `M`, a list

```
list= {{1,1}, {1,3}, {2,3}};
```

and a list of

```
values = {a,b,c}
```

How do I set the matrix elements `{M[[1,1]], M[[1,3]], M[[2,3]]} = values`?

This will produce the list elements I want:

```
Map[P[[Apply[Sequence, #]]] &, list] = {M[[1,1]], M[[1,3]], M[[2,3]]}
```

but the final command is `Map`, which is protected, and hence I cannot use it to set the list elements to the elements of values.

Of course one way of doing this is by looping,

```
For[i=1, i<=Length[list], i++, M[[Sequence @@ list[[i]] = values[[i]]]
```

However, since I would like to work with very large lists of indices I want to avoid loops as much as possible.

Comment: You can directly do `{M[[1, 1]], M[[1, 3]], M[[2, 3]]} = values`? Or do you want it automated?

Comment: Yes, I want to have it automated because I want to work with much larger lists of matrix elements.

Comment: I also want to avoid loops, otherwise `For[i=1, i<=Length[list], i++, M[[Sequence @@ list[[i]] = values[[i]]]` would be an easy solution.

Comment: Are you *modifying* an existing matrix? Or are you declaring the matrix first and then putting in entries? Because if you are just making the matrix to begin with, you can do `M = Normal@SparseArray[Thread[list -> values], {3, 3}]`.

Comment: @march Can it be done with `##`? To pass `list` and `values` like in `M[[1, 1]] = a`. I attempted `M[[##]] & /@ list = values` but failed.

Comment: @corey979. Nevermind, (if you looked at my previous comment which I have just deleted). Something like `Evaluate[m[[Sequence @@ #]] & /@ list] = values` just won't work. You need the `Evaluate` in order to keep *Mathematica* from trying to assign `values` as a `Downvalues` of `Map`, but by evaluating the left-hand side, you replace `m[[Sequence@@ #]]` with the actual value, and you end up setting the *value* stored in that spot to the value in `values`, which won't work if the element isn't symbolic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the structure that you've set up, I would probably accomplish this using `MapThread`. Taking

```
list = {{1, 1}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}};
values = {a, b, c};
m = ConstantArray[1, {3, 3}]
(* {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}} *)
```

do:

```
MapThread[(m[[Sequence @@ #1]] = #2) &, {list, values}];
m
(* {{a, 1, b}, {1, 1, c}, {1, 1, 1}} *)
```

Alternatively,

```
Scan[(m[[Sequence @@ list[[#]]]] = values[[#]]) &, Range@Length@list];
```

But if you are actually just creating the matrix to begin with, I would use `SparseArray` to construct the matrix from scratch, i.e.

```
Normal@SparseArray[Thread[list -> values], {3, 3}]
(* {{a, 0, b}, {0, 0, c}, {0, 0, 0}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly also with a small caveat I forgot to add to the question.

Comment: If I would like to keep the old values and add up the values at these indices, then `MapThread[(m[[Sequence @@ #1]] += #2) &, {list, values}];` does the job, but SparseArray and ReplacePart would erase the old values.

Comment: But if that was the case, then I would do something like `m = m + SparseArray[Thread[list -> values], {3, 3}]`.

Comment: What if the first list you feed already has duplicates which need to be added up? Then seems not easy to do this without introducing some iterative process or loop.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `ReplacePart` and get around the difficulties with `Set`

```
m = ConstantArray[1, {3, 3}]
m = ReplacePart[m, Thread[list -> values]]
(* {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}} *)
(* {{a, 1, b}, {1, 1, c}, {1, 1, 1}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

for fun we can do this all with `SparseArray`..

```
m = Partition[Range[12], 3];
list = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {4, 3}};
values = {a, b, c};
m = SparseArray[list -> 0, Dimensions@m, 1] m + 
          SparseArray[list -> values, Dimensions@m]
```

> {{a, b, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, c}}

or even

```
m + SparseArray[list -> values - Extract[m, list], Dimensions@m]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {{1, 1}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}};
values = {a, b, c};
m = Array[1 &, {3, 3}];
```

Combining `ApplyTo` (new in 12.2) and `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
m //= ReplaceAt[Thread[list -> values], All];

m
```

{{a, 1, b}, {1, 1, c}, {1, 1, 1}

Answer (score 2):

Using `SubsetMap`:

```
list = {{1, 1}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}};
values = {a, b, c};
m = ConstantArray[1, {3, 3}];

SubsetMap[values &, m, list]

(*{{a, 1, b}, {1, 1, c}, {1, 1, 1}}*)
```

Comment: +1 - This is the way to go!

Comment: Thanks, @eldo! :-)