# Assigning Values of Indexed Variables to Arrays

Tags: equation-solving, list-manipulation, index

New to mma.  I have assigned the results of using Solve to solve 5 variables to 5 indices of a new variable:

```
var = a /@ Range[70, 75]
time = 6
xn3 = Table[idirt[X, time] == -a[X]*itime[X, time], {X, 70, 75}];
sol3  = Solve[xn3, var];
acts[var] /. sol3[[1]]
```

The last line, with the data I have, yields the output:

```
acts[{0.0651511, 0.0660446, 0.0690098, 0.0705071, 0.0738969, 0.0748848}]
```

I now want to assign these values to an array at the indices [70,6],[71,6],[72,6],[73,6],[74,6],[75,6] to correspond to the X and time values but I am a loss at how to do this.  This specific implementation requires non-integer values for time as well; does this need to be implemented using an indexing variable (there is an equal time spacing between all data points) or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: You mean, like, `SparseArray[
 Thread[({#1, 6} & /@ Range[70, 75]) -> 
   First@acts[{0.0651511, 0.0660446, 0.0690098, 0.0705071, 0.0738969, 
      0.0748848}]], {75, 75}]`?

Comment: This works for generating the sparse matrix, but it seems to completely overwrite the previous entries when I iterate the values of time.  Which function should be used to add values to the array once it is created without erasing previous ones (ie. if I am iterating time with a Do loop and using the SparseArray function in the loop)?

Comment: There was a recent question about this very thing: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127530/change-a-list-of-matrix-elements.

Comment: note if the assignment is to a contiguous range of postions you can just do like: `array[[70;;75,6]]=var/.sol3[[1]]`